# Continuous Build & Integration for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, build, continuous-integration

I have a SharePoint 2013 Multi Tenant On-Premise Farm. We have some custom WSPs for various modules, which contain Site Columns, Content Types, Lists and Event Receivers. I was wondering if there is a Continuous Build and Integration process for these kind of solutions for SharePoint development? Basically, we want to automate the Build and Deployment process for SharePoint custom solutions. Please suggest.